# Email Authentication using Google Library

Tags: php, email, smtp, smtp-auth

I am using the following google php library for authenticate the email address.Here is the link:

Library:

[Google Library](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/trunk/smtp_validateEmail.class.php)

Example file :

[EXAMPLE](http://code.google.com/p/php-smtp-email-validation/source/browse/trunk/example2.php)

This code is working fine on local server but on client server it is not validating. and on my client's server it is giving the following error:

```
550-Please turn on SMTP Authentication in your mail client, or login to the
550-IMAP/POP3 server before sending your message.  ns500.mycyberhosting.com
550-(bebazar.be) [149.5.18.169]:53930 is not permitted to relay through this
550 server without authentication.
```

if this is the issue of SMTP Authentication than please let me know how to enable SMTP Authentication on client server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think the better option for SMTP email integration using php [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php) and you can use your email settings or even using GMail to send email to your clients and easy to configure without knowing your domain or server configurations. In PHPmaile you can give authentication to true for authenticated mails and you can debug every status of email by enabling debugging mode